# How do I retrieve the schemaNamingMaster in Active Directory using C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to identify the schema master for a forest using C#.  I know there are some available namespaces using System.DirectoryServices and [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.aspx) but I can't seem to find any sample code that can return this information.

I suppose I could trudge through the configuration partition but I would think there is a namespace that could be used to go directly to the source...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this syntax to work but wonder if it's not the best way to handle this...

```
DirectoryContext dirContext = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer,"domain.com", "Username", "Password");
Forest forest = Forest.GetForest(dirContext);
string schemaMaster = forest.SchemaRoleOwner.Name;
```

or using integrated credentials:

```
Forest forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
string schemaMaster = forest.SchemaRoleOwner.Name;
```